# как исправить ошибку программы excel

Tags: vba

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Private Sub Open_xml(Path, FileName, Sheet, Cell As String)
Dim strTargetFile As String
Dim wb
strTargetFile = Path & "" & FileName
Set wb = Workbooks.OpenXML(FileName:=strTargetFile, LoadOption:=xlXmlLoadImportToList)
wb.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Copy ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Sheet).Range(Cell)
wb.Close False
End Sub
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а где их поставить

Comment: я не знаю где исправить

Comment: Нет никакой ошибки Excel, просто отсутствует файл, либо совсем, либо в той папке, к которой идёт обращение.

Comment: файл в папке есть проверял

Answer (score 0):

В режиме отладки (вторая картинка) нажать Ctrl+G и в открывшемся окне напечатать `?strTargetFile` и нажать Enter. Будет напечатано содержимое этой переменной. Там должен быть полный путь к файлу. Убедится, что он правильный, то есть по этому пути есть этот файл, включая расширение. Для этого лучше всего выкопировать путь от начала и до последнего "\" перед имененм файла и вставить его в строку адреса Проводника Windows. Судя по сообщению об ошибке, расширение файла в strTargetFile - "AGRO_Settings". А какое расширение у файла в папке?

Сказал же, проверьте расширение. Есть файл "XDSD.TQBR.AGRO_Settings.tmp" и "XDSD.TQBR.AGRO_Settings.xml", но нет файла "XDSD.TQBR.AGRO_Settings".

Проверьте в коде место, откуда вызывается процедура "Private Sub Open_xml(Path, FileName, Sheet, Cell As String)". В FileName попадает имя файла без расширения. Нужно разобраться, почему.

Или просто расширение добавить, например, так:

```
Private Sub Open_xml(Path, FileName, Sheet, Cell As String)
  Dim strTargetFile As String
  Dim wb
  strTargetFile = Path & "" & FileName & ".xml" ' <<<<<< добавлено & ".xml"
  Set wb = Workbooks.OpenXML(FileName:=strTargetFile, LoadOption:=xlXmlLoadImportToList)
  wb.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Copy ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Sheet).Range(Cell)
  wb.Close False
End Sub
```